# If vectors $\overrightarrow A$ and $ \overrightarrow B$ are irrotational then prove $\overrightarrow A \times \overrightarrow B$ is solenoidal.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I have given here:

$\operatorname{Curl}(\overrightarrow A) = \overrightarrow 0$ and $\operatorname{Curl}(\overrightarrow B) = \overrightarrow 0$

So, to prove solenoidal the divergence must be zero i.e.:

$$= \nabla \cdot (\overrightarrow E \times \overrightarrow H) $$

Where do I go from here? I came across [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product) which may be applied here in some way I suppose if $\nabla$ is a vector quantity.

Comment: The divergence of the cross product is as follows: $\nabla \cdot (A \times B) = (\nabla \times A) \cdot B - A \cdot (\nabla \times B)$. The [wikipedia page on vector calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) is a pretty valuable resource for problems of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @[stochasticboy321](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269063/stochasticboy321) from comments.

$\operatorname{Curl}(\overrightarrow A) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Curl}(\overrightarrow B) = 0$

So, to prove solenoidal the divergence must be zero i.e.:

$$= \nabla \cdot (\overrightarrow E \times \overrightarrow H) $$

We know,

$ \nabla \cdot (\overrightarrow E \times \overrightarrow H)= \overrightarrow H \cdot ( \nabla \times \overrightarrow E) - \overrightarrow E\cdot(\nabla \times \overrightarrow H) = \overrightarrow H \cdot 0 - \overrightarrow E \cdot 0 = 0 $

Therefore, $ \overrightarrow E \times \overrightarrow H$ is solenoidal.